# Need to optimize a Count Query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to optimize a slow running query written by a ex-colleague. He had not used stored procedure and directly written the queries in ADO.NET, and the queries are too slow.

I am trying to convert the queries into a single SP. This particular `SELECT` statement takes too much of time. @PMasterTable was used logic was used too many times inside the last condition.

```
INSERT INTO @PMasterTable
SELECT R.PId
  FROM PRecord R
  WHERE R.PId IN( @aId , @nId )

SELECT @DeleteCount = COUNT( P.Id )
  FROM Result P
  WHERE(P.Approved IS NULL
     OR P.Approved = 0)
   AND P.ACTION = 'D'
   AND P.Id NOT IN( SELECT Id FROM ARecords )
   AND P.PId IN( SELECT PId FROM @PMasterTable );
```

It's been a while since I wrote SQL queries, so I am a bit rusty!

Comment: Have you done any sort of query plan analysis? Is it slow because your indexes are bad?

Comment: Not yet, I converted the queries first to a SP as it is, almost all queries are some kind of variants of the above SELECT query. I think the query is taking time in NOT IN/IN conditions cause the result is large.

Comment: Have you tried with Temporary table instead of Variable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT @DeleteCount = COUNT( P.Id )
  FROM Result P 
  join @PMasterTable 
    on @PMasterTable.PId  = P.PId 
   and (   P.Approved IS NULL
        OR P.Approved = 0)
   AND P.ACTION = 'D'
  left join ARecords
    on ARecords.Id = P.Id 
 where ARecords.Id is null
```

And I think count(*) would be the same answer here

without the @PMasterTable

```
SELECT @DeleteCount = COUNT( P.Id )
  FROM Result P 
  join PRecord R
    on r.PId  = P.PId 
   and (   P.Approved IS NULL
        OR P.Approved = 0)
   and P.ACTION = 'D'
   and r.PId IN( @aId , @nId )
  left join ARecords
    on ARecords.Id = P.Id 
 where ARecords.Id is null
```

By pulling the conditions into the join the query optimizer seems to do better with filtering early.
Especially that and r.PId IN( @aId , @nId ) most likely you want applied early.

And depending on the indexes and table size then this may be faster (remove the r.PId)

```
and P.PId IN( @aId , @nId )
```

Comment: Aren't you trying to join against a TempTable [@PMasterTable] that isnt even being created in this instance?

Comment: @Talspaugh27 If at PMasterTable is not available then why does the insert work?

Comment: in the original it is inserting INTO @PMastertable and then using that table to join the selected values. it would be better NOT to populate that temp table and strictly go from the queried values themselves.
And you are correct, the table has been Declared, but not populated, Sorry I misspoke on my comment.

Comment: @Talspaugh27 You don't know that.  That might be an expensive query that only returns a few rows and is also used elsewhere.

Comment: True, I was taking in context that it was ONLY populated with the original query. But I think it would be better practice to avoid the cost of creating the temp table if possible. The OP also says "PMasterTable was used" which seems to state that using it was one of the things they were trying to avoid?!?

Comment: Strange, I used your first query, same result i.e., takes lot of time, but later I added option(recompile) at the end of the query and it executed within seconds. On another note, I tried option(recompile) couple of days ago (when the queries were still been executed from ADO.NET, it was fast for a day and then went back to same speed). Currently running as query in SSMS and not as a SP.

Comment: We are getting somewhere here, the querie took less than one second to execute, that was 5+ minutes. I have used in the option(recompile) in two places which takes lot of time, I guess that shouldn't be used like that. Will further investigate.

Comment: Pretty sure with the at MasterTable the optimizer is not aware it has two or less rows and does a lot of other work first.  Once the query optimizer figures it out it typically will remember.

Answer (score 0):

Combining the 2 queries would only require you to change it to (without running this through sql to parse it)

```
SELECT @DeleteCount = COUNT( P.Id )
FROM Result P
inner join PRecord R on R.PId = P.PId 
    and R.PId IN( @aId , @nId )
WHERE isnull(P.Approved, 0) = 0 
AND P.ACTION = 'D'
AND P.Id NOT IN( SELECT Id FROM ARecords )
```

unfortunately this probably WON'T resolve your speed issue. What columns are indexed on the "Result" Table and the "PRecord" table

Answer (score 0):

as general recommandation based on your query :

replace is null or = X by isnull(variable,X) = X. It could change your execution plan and solve an or problem
Replace your Value not in (query) by not exists (query where column = Value). The exist stop searching your value when the condition is completed not at the end of the query it could speed up too.

But this is general advise it should not solve a big issue.
One last, sometimes it's require to avoir a problem of execution plan, but do you know why you have 2 querys and not a subquery in the last one?
Are you using the other table somewhere else?

Here is the code

```
SELECT @DeleteCount = COUNT( P.Id )
  FROM Result P
  inner join PRecord R on r.pid = p.pid
  WHERE isnull(P.Approved,0) = 0
   AND P.ACTION = 'D'
   AND not exists  ( SELECT * FROM ARecords as a where a.ID = P.Id)
  and R.PId IN( @aId , @nId )
```

Answer (score 0):

Using "IN" or "NOT IN" with subqueries can cause performance problems. And then you don't really need the data in the subqueries for you're only checking if such value exists or not.

Try this:

```
SELECT @DeleteCount = COUNT( P.Id )
  FROM Result P
  WHERE(P.Approved IS NULL
     OR P.Approved = 0)
   AND P.ACTION = 'D'
   AND NOT EXISTS (
       SELECT 1 FROM ARecords AR WHERE AR.ID= P.Id )
   AND EXISTS (
       SELECT 1 FROM @PMasterTable PM WHERE PM.PId = P.PId);
```